# PostgreSQL doesn't respond when I input stranger character on CMD

Tags: postgresql, cmd

Previously, had appeared warning about inconsistency between chcp with windows code page (like [that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171490/warning-console-code-page-437-differs-from-windows-code-page-1252-8-bit-cha)) when start psql. When input or output consist stranger character gave an error. I changed chcp to 65001 and made windows code page utf-8 thus the error problem solved. Now psql show stranger characters smoothly. But when I input stranger character it doesn't respond notification or error or anything else and doesn't pass to other line. Only waiting. Then I have to quit.

Note: On the image the values which consist stranger characters entered with pgAdmin not CMD.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem (no answer from the PG mailing list and no solution on a similar post in DBA stack exchange). I fell back on having 2 settings: a local (1252 in my case) CHCP + WIN1252 client encoding for inputs, and a 65001 + utf8 client_encoding for displaying. A real pain to be honest

Comment: You don't have to quit. You can type `';` to get back to a working prompt

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269260/psql-console-encoding

Comment: Unfortunately there is no special CHCP for my language (azerbaijanese) thus I have to set encoding utf-8 for both of inputs and outputs;

Comment: How did you set different encoding to input and displaying separately? Maybe I can set WIN1254 for inputs. It is similar to my language.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9D2vzT8008

Comment: @lit it doesn't work. There is no special windows emulation page for azerbaijanese ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_emulation_code_pages ). I can only use UTF-8.

Comment: I added a switch in `runplsql.bat`. It means I need 2 open consoles, 1 for input and a 2nd one for display:  `SET encoding_type=1
SET /P encoding_type="Encoding WIN1252 (1) or UTF8 (2) [%encoding_type%]: "

if %encoding_type%==1 (
 chcp 1252
 SET PGCLIENTENCODING=WIN1252
) else (
 chcp 65001
 SET PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8
)`